# How to target span by class name and get ID then pass ID in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to **get id of a span in a dropdown which has classname and id is dynamic but classname is always fixed** so I tried this `document.querySelector(".tag").id` and this is working when I select the span from dropdown but when I did not select anything from dropdown my ajax gives an error `main.js:357 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')` which is clearly for this, How will I pass this span id so that if I select or not it should be pass in ajax?

why is it happening?

**update:**

I have tried this

```
  const element = document.querySelector(".tag");

  if (element) {
    jourid = element.id + "_" + $("#tags_input").val();
  } else {
    jourid = " ";
  }
```

```
but now it says jourid not define if I am not selecting the value ! how will i resolve this ?

<span id="249257" class="tag"><span>Test</span><a href="javascript:void(0)">x</a></span>
```

```
$(function () {
    var frm = $("#saveform");
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr("method"),
        url: frm.attr("action"),

        data: {
          PubId: $("#Publications").val(),
          sdate: $("#datepicker").val(),
          jour:document.querySelector(".tag").id,
          pnumber: $("#pnumber").val(),
        },
        cache: false,
        error: function (err, data) {
          console.log("There was an error. Try again please!" + data, err);
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert( "Saved!");
          window.location.reload();
        },
      });
    });
  });
```

**How will I pass the id of span so that there will be successful ajax call whether value is empty or not?**

Comment: From what i can gather, this seems like the backend does not handle request without `id` field value, and returns error. if possible change the backend to handle requests without having the `id` field. if this is not the case, please post the error message when it fails

Comment: @bitDaft I am using PHP in Backend!

Comment: Can you add the error message you receive when it fails? does it fail from backend, or is the ajax call itself not occuring?

Comment: @bitDaft Hi I got this error `main.js:357 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')` also updated my question summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occuring because the `document.querySelector` was not able to find any `span` elements.

You only need to add a check on whether the query return any element before accessing `id` field of it.

something like this:

```js
frm.submit(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  // this will set `undefined` to id if the span element is not obtained
  var id = document.querySelector(".tag")?.id; 

  // now you can error check here and return if needed
  // if(!id) return;
  
  //or set id as empty
  if(!id) id = " ";

  $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr("method"),
        url: frm.attr("action"),
        data: {
          // ...,
          jour: id,
          // ...
        },
        ...
      });
}
```

as for the `jourid not defined`, you just need to write `let jourid;` before using the variable in if statment, like so

```js
  let jourid;
  if (element) {
    jourid = element.id + "_" + $("#tags_input").val();
  } else {
    jourid = " ";
  }
```

Comment: if `(id)` then I should pass empty value otherwise ajax will fail again,

Comment: Although i have given an answer, i am not sure your way of getting the `id` is correct. if you are using a dropdown to select, then there should already be a way to obtain the selected value without resorting to such "hacky" methods. if you are using a library for the dropdown, check the documentation to see how you can retrieve the selected value.